# For $\phi(x,y)=(x,y+\psi (x))$ with $\psi:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ integrable, show that $\phi (B)$ is measurable for every box $B\subset \Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, volume

Let $\psi:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ be integrable and define $\phi:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^2$ by $\phi(x,y)=(x,y+\psi (x))$. Prove that for every box $B\subset \Bbb{R}^2$, $\phi(B)$ is measureable and $v(\phi (B))=v(B)$.

**Remarks:**

- In the original question, the term used is "admissible" rather than "measurable"
- Admissibility of a set $A$ was conditioned, by definition, by the integrability of $1_A$.

I know that $\psi$ must be bounded, and I can picture $\phi(B)$ for $B=[a,b]\times [c,d]$, and it does seem intuitively like uncountably many shifting(for all $a\le x\le b$) in a way that preserves the volume of $B$. So, intuitively the volume of the second coordinate remains the same, but the first coordinate is an uncountable union, and I can't understand how to approach computing its volume. My ideal method would be using $1_A$ kind of function, but this time, $A$ is $x$-dependent. I also considered using $\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c+\psi(x)}^{d+\psi(x)}1dydx$, but I have no way to justify it and could use your help.

Comment: What is $\nu$ in your question?

Comment: $v$ stands for "volume".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you already know that $\nu([a,b])=b-a$, so $\nu([a+\psi(x),b+\psi(x)])=b+\psi(x)-(a+\psi(x))=b-a$ for any fixed $x$.

Looks worse than it is:

$L_N(\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]\times[c+\psi(x),d+\psi(x)]}(x,y))=2^{-2N}\sum_{k,l \in \mathbb{Z}}\inf_{x \in \frac{k}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\inf_{y \in \frac{l}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]\times[c+\psi(x),d+\psi(x)]}(x,y)=2^{-2N}\sum_{k,l \in \mathbb{Z}}\inf_{x \in \frac{k}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\inf_{y \in \frac{l}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]\times[c,d]}(x,y+\psi(x))=2^{-2N}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{l\in \mathbb{Z}}\inf_{x \in \frac{k}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\inf_{y \in \frac{l}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(x)\mathbf{1}_{[c,d]}(y+\psi(x)) =^{*} 2^{-2N}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\inf_{x \in \frac{k}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\sum_{l\in \mathbb{Z}}\inf_{y \in \frac{l}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(x)\mathbf{1}_{[c,d]}(y+\psi(x)) = 2^{-N}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\inf_{x \in \frac{k}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(x)2^{-N}\sum_{l\in \mathbb{Z}}\inf_{y \in \frac{l}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{[c,d]}(y+\psi(x)) =2^{-N}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\inf_{x \in \frac{k}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(x)L_N(\mathbf{1}_{[c+\psi(x),d+\psi(x)]}(y))\geq2^{-N}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\inf_{x \in \frac{k}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(x)L_N(\mathbf{1}_{(c+\psi(x),d+\psi(x))}(y))\geq 2^{-N}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\inf_{x \in \frac{k}{2^{N}}+[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(x)((d+\psi(x)-(c+\psi(x))-2^{-N+1})=L_N(\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(x))((d-c)-2^{-N+1})\rightarrow (b-a)(d-c)$ as $ N \rightarrow \infty$
The last inequality is due to the hint on page 58.
Use the same hint to show in the same fashion:

$U_N(\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]\times[c+\psi(x),d+\psi(x)]}(x,y)) \leq U_N(\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(x))(d-c+2^{-N+1}) \rightarrow (b-a)(d-c)$

The first inequality was just so you could refer to an open ball like you have in the hint, you wont need it for the $U_N$.

I have to work $=^{*}$ out, made a little mistake, give me some time...

The reason for $=^{*}$ is, that for any fixed $N$ looking at the indicator functions we see that only finitely many $k,l$ can result in a value other than 0, so there are some finite sets $A,B$ of natural numbers, such that $\sum_k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\sum_l \in \mathbb{Z} $ might be replaced with $\sum_k \in A$ and $\sum_l \in B $ then switching $\inf$ and finite sum is ok and then you just replace the sets back to $\mathbb{Z}$, because this means adding zero.

Comment: That was hideous, if i had not promised it, I wouldn't have done it. xD
If this solves your issue please award the bounty.

Comment: I think OP can judge by himself if he wants to award you the bounty, no need to remind him.

Comment: I actually had the case were an OP was very satisfied with my answer but forgot to award the bounty, so I won't get any. :'(
Look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810325/interlacing-stopping-times/1821472#1821472

Comment: Seems I misunderstood something.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I am going through it right not. The effort put here is beyond appreciable and it seems to satisfy my requirements. No words to express my gratitude. Please let me follow it so as to make sure I understand it. You were truly so attentive and the work you've done, adjusting yourself to my notations will be well remembered.

Comment: Can you explain why it is allowed to take the infimum gradually? I mean, infimum of an infimum? Because, I wasn't able to tell whether the value which gives the infimum in one coordinate is invariant.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you ask...

Answer (score 1):

Here we go: I think you mean $\nu=\lambda^2$, the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$\nu(\phi(B)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{\phi(B)}d\lambda^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{\phi(B)}d\lambda d\lambda=$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{\phi(B)}(x,y)dy dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{\phi(B)}(x,y+\psi(x))dy dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{B}(x,y)dy dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{B}d\lambda d\lambda=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{B}d\lambda^2=\nu(B)$
The first equality and the last are by definition, the second follows from Fubinis theorem, the third from the transformation formular, the rest are definitions again.

I assume there will be questions left, go ahead.

Comment: First, thank you for your elaborated and explained answer- really appreciate it. 
Oddly enough, (taking the course again with another prof. whose notations are less conventional), I didn't get to see those Lambdas, and I don't quite understand what they mean as a variable. We did discuss Lebesgue Criterion but the integrals were mostly around oscillations, upper and lower integrals.

Comment: We were presented with $U(f)=\lim_\limits{N\to \infty}\sum_{k\in \Bbb{Z}^n} 2^{-nN}\underset{x\in 2^{-N}{([0,1]^n+k)}}{\sup} f$, and the lower sum goes in the same fashion. I tried to use those to show integrability with no success, and I thought I am no allowed to use integrals without showing integrability (which is the lower and upper sums being equal). I mean, the processes above assume integrability, right? How is integrability shown to begin with? What is your notion of that?

Comment: I see, what I wrote is the Analysis3 standard. You seem not able to use it. Tiered now but tomorrow I will explain that $\lambda$, which is no variable, but a measure. I also want to give you an answer you can use, is there a link to the script you use? Otherwise, please give your mathematical definition of $\nu$ (or are you from physics?) and how it relates to the integral, if you know that. Best regards.

Comment: I am so glad to have you listen carefully to my problems. I am inexplicably frustrated and have been trying to get something for **hours**. I use these notes "http://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/Courses/Analysis3/main.html", written by my professor, Boris Tsirelson. This is a question written by him, and to what I have learned, his exams are FAIR, meaning it is supposed to be quite direct, but I can't seem to find the tools he would want me to use.

Comment: A volume of a set $A\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ is $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} 1_A$ assuming $A$ is admissible (that is, assuming $1_A$ is integrable). That's what we were given.

Comment: Again, I really appreciate your approach.

Comment: Have been trying my problems for 3 days and nights straight now. Needing hours is normal. I will finish this in 10 h.

Comment: Link seems broken...

Comment: http://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/Courses/Analysis3/main.html

Comment: The volume is defined in the fourth note...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41064/discussion-between-thomas-e-and-meitar-abarbanel).

Comment: How can I use the chat?